# Aws Vpc flow logs to athena from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-vpc

[image]I'm planning to push my vpc flow logs which are currently in s3 to be stored in athena. 
Whenever vpc flow logs push the log file to  s3 event will be triggered to send the data to athena and check if there is any data greater then 30days delete it.

Any suggestion??

My opinion: to put the logs in redshift using copy command.

Query used :
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vpc_flow_logs (
  version int,
  account string,
  interfaceid string,
  sourceaddress string,
  destinationaddress string,
  sourceport int,
  destinationport int,
  protocol int,
  numpackets int,
  numbytes bigint,
  starttime int,
  endtime int,
  action string,
  logstatus string
)
PARTITIONED BY (`date` date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
LOCATION 's'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data is not "stored" in Amazon Athena.** Instead, a table is configured in Amazon Athena that **points to the data** located in Amazon S3.

When a query runs in Amazon Athena, it automatically looks at **all files in that location**.

Therefore, there is no need to move or copy the log files. Simply point the Athena table to where the log files are currently stored.

If you wish to delete old logs (to have only 30 days of data), configure [Amazon S3 Object lifecycle management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) to delete files after 30 days.

See: [Querying Amazon VPC Flow Logs - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/vpc-flow-logs.html)

If you expect to analyze the data often, then it might be worthwhile loading the data into Amazon Redshift. This is because Amazon Athena is charged based on the amount of data read from disk. Therefore, **running many queries across the data can be more expensive**. Alternatively, you could convert the log files into compressed Parquet format, which makes it much more efficient for Athena to query, thereby lowering the amount of data read from disk and thus lowering the cost of using Athena. However, start with the above recommendation and see how much you end up using Athena before making a change.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean i have to manually run the query and create the table every time when I want to analyse the logs??

Comment: You only need to create the table once. It points at the folder where the VPC Flow Logs are stored, including all subdirectories. Whenever new logs appear in that location, they will automatically be included in the next Athena query. Similarly, if data files are deleted (eg by the lifecycle rule), the data will _not_ be included in the next query. Athena just queries whatever files are in that location at the time that the query is run.

Comment: Thanks, i have created the table but whenever i do preview table its not point to data

Comment: What happens when you query the table? Make sure that the `LOCATION` was is correctly when you create the table.

Comment: i an this query : 
ALTER TABLE vpc_flow_logs
ADD PARTITION (`date`='2020-05-25')
location 's3://test1234cm/logs';
 then data was populated . what will happen if i add data tomorrow do i need to alter again ?  what automation i must use ?    
This query creates a single partition only, for a date that you specify. To automate the process, use a script that runs this query and creates partitions this way for the year/month/day.   any suggestion

Comment: AH! It's due to the partitioning. You can either add single partitions (as you did), or you can run [MSCK REPAIR TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html), which will scan for new partitions. Yes, it's a bit of extra work, but it greatly saves time (and money!) by using partitioning, since Athena can skip-over directories that do not contain the desired date. Try to use the `date` field in your WHERE clauses as much as possible, so it can take advantage of the partitioning.

Comment: Thanks, it means whenever I have to query data before running select I have to run msck repair table query which will automatically add new partitions. No need to run alter table command everytime

Comment: Correct. Alter Table will be faster (almost instant), while `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` will need to scan all folders so it takes a bit longer. Only needed after the partitioning has changed (eg folders added/removed).